# How to execute/compile this github

Tags: github, makefile, cygwin

I guess this question is pretty noobish and I googled a lot for it, but how can i make the following github files running or how to compile it?

https://github.com/Keyaku/ps4tools

Is it possible with cygwin? If yes, Id appreciate help of how to do it.

Thank you,
Ginsor

Comment: The best solution would probably open an issue on the GitHub repository and ask the author to extend the Readme. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the needed tools installed in cygwin:
  git, make, gcc ...

```
git clone https://github.com/Keyaku/ps4tools
cd ps4tools
make clean
make
```

`make clean` is needed as upstream put also the binaries under github and that is really noobish.